# Recursive scan for files with xgettext

Tags: linux, localization, xgettext

I need to recursively scan all folders from a project for xgettext strings. How can this be done using xgettext on linux?

My current parameters are: 
--default-domain=project -k_

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
find . -iname "*.php" | xargs xgettext --from-code=UTF-8 --default-domain=project
```

This should do the trick.